# Github Actions, Python Coverage and Sonar Qube

Tags: sonarqube, pytest, github-actions

I want to create a Github workflow that does the following:

1. test my code with `pytest`
2. trigger Sonar Qube Cloud to analyze to the code and show my test coverage!

As far as I understand, SonarQ needs a file `coverage.xml` to display the code coverage. This can be generated with

```sh
pytest --cov=./ --cov-report=xml --doctest-modules
```

According to [this article](https://dev.to/remast/go-for-sonarcloud-with-github-actions-3pmn) `coverage.xml` should be available under `/github/workspace/coverage.xml`.

Thus, I specify my `sonar-project.properties` in the root folder of the project:

```
sonar.organization=pokemate
sonar.projectKey=PokeMate_name-generator
sonar.sources=.
sonar.python.coverage.reportPath=/github/workspace/coverage.xml
```

my actions file `build.yml`:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - develop
      - sonar-qube-setup

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on:
      - ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # Checkout repo
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Dependencies
      - name: Set up Python 3.7
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: 3.7

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt

      # Test
      - name: Test with pytest
        run: |
          pytest --cov=./ --cov-report=xml --doctest-modules

      # Sonar Qube
      - name: SonarCloud Scan
        uses: sonarsource/sonarcloud-github-action@master
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
```

However, on SonarQ it still shows 0% test coverage, which is probably because it cannot find the `coverage.xml`. Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Did you find any way? im trying the same and facing same issue.

Comment: Just added an answer why it did not work for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error came from the missing `s` in `reportPaths` in the `sonar-project.properties` file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Im working on to fix this issues.. if i get any solution i will post here.